# What can I use as a waterproof shield for my Rycote?

Tags: sound-effects-recording

Hi everyone, im looking at doing some recording of smashing up fruit/vegetables and i want to make sure i dont mess up my gear by getting any juice/water etc all over my Softie. Is there a decent way i can put something over it that will give a little protection that wont get in the way of my recordings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend a pop screen/shield as used for vocal recording, or a wire clothes hanger with pantyhose/nylon hosiery stretched over it. Not waterproof, but the tension and small gaps will probably catch most of the watery goop. Using anything less porous would probably color the sound. If you need something larger, stretch similar material over a DIY frame of PVC piping, held in place by appropriate grip equipment.

You're using a softie, but a rigid zepp or blimp will largely do the same thing as described above, and you can wash or rinse them off. A good reason to own a (relatively cheap) Røde blimp as a "stunt zeppelin!"

Comment: Thanks! Iv got an old pretty large pop shield i could use. Never thought about one of those! Should stop most the direct juice/debris from getting on my gear :) 

Answer (score 4):

I use a old window screen with a towel laid over it on top of a 12 foot pole. keeps the rain from hitting. The towel will get too wet but then I swap it out for a dry one. Stay away from the Rycote duck, I have it and it is worthless

Comment: Good to know since I was thinking about buying that Rycote duck. I will try your towel trick the next few days when it's raining again.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mess up your softie/pop screen something like this might work : [image]
<sub>(source: [edelstahl-in-bestform.de](http://www.edelstahl-in-bestform.de/bilder_gross_con/b3103_pfannen_spritzschutz.jpg))</sub>

Don't know how it's called in english, but it's one of those things you put on top of your pan.

But as NoiseJockey alreadys said: you can wash everything off.

Comment: That is called a splatter guard here in the US, and is a great repurposing of existing tech!

Answer (score 2):

This is a full on rain cover: [Remote Audio REM-RMAN Rainman Boom Mic Rain Cover](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/556123-REG/Remote_Audio_RMAN_REM_RMAN_Rainman_Boom_Mic.html)

Could work for your needs, but might be a little over kill. I always travel with it for shoots, but I haven't actually needed to use it, so I'm not sure how well it works.

Comment: I also recommend the RA Rainman for light rain, but won't really protect from front-facing splatters that well. One could put it on backwards, but it will definitely color the sound.

Answer (score 0):

A plastic bag works. It modifies the sound slightly, my guess you will not notice it. Does not work with rain as the drops makes a sound. But recording sound effects, the "splash" might actually add to the sound.